Is there a way to disable touch input in android app when the device is remotely controlled?
So i'm currently trying to make an app that is secure enough to not be seen and operated through remote technology such as TeamViewer and other similar apps.
The app only has two buttons that displays a toast on click. I managed to hide the screen using FLAG_SECURE, FLAG_SECURE basically makes the screen black when viewed through non-secure displays (remotely).
But i noticed that even though the screen is black, i can still tap the button from the controller device. Is there a way to disable touch input when the device is remotely controlled?
I tried asking ChatGPT and other AI services but the solutions given did not seem feasible. I'm wondering if there is a proper way to do this.
